# How to use cell values to define the range of chart data?

Tags: excel, reference, range, cell

I have a set of 500 cells from which I've created a chart using the following range definition:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$500
```

I have 2 cells `B1` and `B2` in which I would like to define start and end values (inside 1-500) for the chart to show only a subset of my data (let's say from 20 to 200).

**How can I reference the cells `B1` and `B2` to replace `$1` and `$500` in my data range definition?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, you should use dynamic charts with **calculated named ranges** with help of `OFFSET` and `COUNTA` used in `SERIES` function that defines chart series.

It's pretty much to explain here, but here is my own sample file created for staff training: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5enub45nn4y36gz/DynamicCharts4Types.xlsx

It includes 4 different types of applied dynamics, such as show last X points, show points from X to Y, etc. To see the magic go to Ribbon `Formulas > Name Manager` and check how different ranges are defined.

Comment: Sample file is really great, +1 for just sharing it!

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your query correctly then You can use `.SetSourceData` and adding the values from `B1` and `B2`

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Please amend the code as applicable
Sub Sample()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim StartVal As Long, endVal As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        StartVal = .Range("B1").Value
        endVal = .Range("B2").Value

        Set objChrt = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
        Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

        chrt.SetSourceData (.Range("A" & StartVal & ":A" & endVal))

    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, meant I didn't want to use VBA